# How do we close answered questions that never had one accepted?

Tags: discussion

By my calculation there are around 7710 unanswered questions in the vba tag. Many of these have answers, but no accepted answer. Is there any process by which we "close" or accept answers on behalf of users who have apparently abandoned their questions?

Comment: Just because the questions don't get any traction right now, doesn't mean the askers abandoned it at all. What if he is still waiting for a good answer to come along?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: You can check when the user last logged in = You can at least check who abandoned the *site*.

Comment: That's a very good point @JeroenVannevel. I hadn't thought of it, but you're right. The problem I see though is that there is a large number of questions with what seem like very legitimate answers. I've creeped SO for a long time, but only recently became what I'd call an active member of the community. I was just wondering if there was a mechanism for this.

Comment: Your use of the word close is incorrect.  "Closing" is the act of closing a question because it doesn't fit within the guidelines of the site.  If it is an on-topic question, there is no reason to close it.

Comment: Still, it would be cumbersome and would defeat one of the community aspects: if you would close it and someone would come along with the same problem, he would have to duplicate that problem while it was closed for.. for what reason exactly?

Comment: Ok. So "closing" isn't the right word, but does anyone see what I'm saying and asking? It's hard to crawl through "unanswered" questions looking to supply answers when there are so many that already have legitimate answers that were never accepted.

Comment: I would just like to know what the process is for this... I'm still having trouble finding the correct wording.

Comment: Do you mean you wish to have a way to find questions that have 0 answers?

Comment: @ckuhn203 what you are asking is a very common question that the community is very much against.  "Accepting" is the act of the original poster saying "This helped me the most".  "Voting" is the act of the community saying "This is the best answer".

Comment: Yes @Oded. That is partly what I'm saying.

Comment: [Here's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature) the most common duplicate target on Meta.SE for this feature request.  You should look at the "Linked" section in the sidebar there to see how many questions are linked and the various discussions.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Which makes sense. I was just wondering if the community had a way of "policing" users who show up once, post a question and never accept an answer.

Comment: Ok. [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3717/256822) explained it very well to me. Thank you @psubsee2003.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are (currently) 3,628 questions tagged with [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba), that have no answers at all.

The search supports querying by the number of answers a question has (in this case, 0):

```
[vba] answers:0
```

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+answers%3A0

Comment: Fantastic. While it doesn't really answer my question. It does solve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: IMHO the statistics about tags should use this number, not the "hasaccepted:1" criterion which varies so much across tags depending on the relative generosity in accepting answers that askers have.